# Codeigniter loads views from functions on top of another

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page at `admin/show_queries` with a form in codeigniter like so

```
<form action="" method = "post">
    <input....
    <input....
    <input type = "submit" name = "view_query" />
</form>
```

Then in my controller `Admin.php`, I try to catch the event when someone presses `view_query`

```
public function show_queries(){

...
...

  if($this->input=>post('view_query'){
     $this->view_query_function();
  }

  $this->load->view('elex/show_queries');
}
```

In the same file `Admin.php` my `view_query_function`:

```
public function view_query_function(){
   //DO Something
   ...
   ...
   $this->load->view('elex/view_queries');
}
```

All of this is working and I'm able to go to the `View_queries` page without trouble.
Here's the problem, that I'm facing<

When I click the button `view_queries` and the `view_queries` page loads, it loads on top of `show_queries` page. Means, when the `view_queries` page is loaded, I can scroll down and I see the `show_queries` page, which should not be there. I check the url, and the url hasn't changed either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a return after calling the function:

```
 if($this->input->post('view_query'){
     $this->view_query_function();
     return;
  }
```